# Doubly linked list confusion

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I created doubly linked list and 2 functions. The first function prints the list from start to end and the second function prints the list from back to start. In the second function I set the first node->prev to NULL but

- I do not understand why the first function actually works because I have never set the last node's next pointer to NULL so in my opinion it should create an infinite loop.

Here is the code :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class LinkedList
{
    struct Node 
    {
        int data;
        Node * next;
        Node * prev;
    };

    public:
           LinkedList    ( void );
      void AddToList     ( int val );
      void FrontToBack   ( void ) const;
      void BackToFront   ( void ) const; 

    private:
        Node * head;
        Node * n;
        Node * tail;
};

LinkedList::LinkedList ( void )
{
    head = NULL;
    n = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void LinkedList::AddToList ( int val )
{
    n = new Node ( );
    n -> data = val;
    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        n -> prev = NULL;
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    }
    else
    {
        n -> prev = tail;
        tail -> next = n;
        tail = n;
    }
}

void LinkedList::FrontToBack ( void ) const
{
    Node * tmp = head;
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Printing list from head to tail:" << endl; 

    while ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        if ( ! size )
        {
            cout << tmp -> data;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " " << tmp -> data;
            tmp = tmp -> next;
        }
        ++ size;
    }

    cout << endl;
}

void LinkedList::BackToFront ( void ) const
{
    Node * tmp = tail;
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Printing list from tail to head:" << endl;

    while ( tmp != NULL )
    {
        if ( ! size )
        {
            cout << tmp -> data;
            tmp = tmp -> prev;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " " << tmp -> data;
            tmp = tmp -> prev;
        }
        ++ size;
    }

    cout << endl;
}



int main ( void )
{

    LinkedList list;

    list.AddToList( 1 );
    list.AddToList( 2 );
    list.AddToList( 3 );
    list.AddToList( 4 );
    list.AddToList( 5 );
    list.AddToList( 6 );

    list.FrontToBack( );
    list.BackToFront( );

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You simply have undefined behavior with accessing uninitialized member variables of `Node`, anything can happen including seemingly correct behavior.

Comment: Perhaps the default value of `Node::next` is `nullptr`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so i do not need to even set `n -> prev = NULL;` in the first node?

Comment: @kvway No, you are ***always responsible*** to initialize all the member variables correctly. I said anything can happen, there's no guarantee that it will behave as you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - I do not understand why the first function actually works because I have never set the last node's next pointer to NULL so in my opinion it should create an infinite loop.

The `next` and `prev` pointers of `struct Node` are never initialized, thus accessing and dereferencing them is undefined behavior. This means you cannot expect any specific behavior like *looping infinitely*.

To ensure defined behavior just default initialize the pointers in your `Node` struct:

```
struct Node 
{
    int data;
    Node * next;
    Node * prev;

    Node() : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {} // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```